# R - Reducing a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a square matrix that is like:

```
A <- c("111","111","111","112","112","113")
B <- c(100,10,20,NA,NA,10)
C <- c(10,20,40,NA,10,20)
D <- c(10,20,NA,NA,40,200)
E <- c(20,20,40,10,10,20)
F <- c(NA,NA,40,100,10,20)
G <- c(10,20,NA,30,10,20)

df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
names(df) <- c("Codes","111","111","111","112","112","113")

#   Codes 111 111 111 112 112 113
# 1   111 100  10  10  20  NA  10
# 2   111  10  20  20  20  NA  20
# 3   111  20  40  NA  40  40  NA
# 4   112  NA  NA  NA  10 100  30
# 5   112  NA  10  40  10  10  10
# 6   113  10  20 200  20  20  20
```

I want to reduce it so that observations with the same row and column names are summed up.
So I want to end up with:

```
#   Codes 111 112 113
# 1   111 230 120  30
# 2   112  50 130  40
# 3   113 230  40  20
```

I tried to first combine the rows with the same "Codes" number, but I was having a lot of trouble.

Comment: To be clear, that's a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`.

Comment: It also has duplicated column names, which I would not recommend using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   pivot_longer(-Codes, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(Codes, name) %>%
   summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')%>%
   pivot_wider()
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Codes `111` `112` `113`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 111     230   120    30
2 112      50   130    40
3 113     230    40    20
```

One way in base R:

```
tapply(unlist(df[-1]), list(names(df)[-1][col(df[-1])], df[,1][row(df[-1])]), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
    111 112 113
111 230  50 230
112 120 130  40
113  30  40  20
```

Note that this can be simplified as denoted by [@thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72652314/r-reducing-a-matrix/72652393#comment128334352_72652393) to

```
 grp <- expand.grid(df$Codes, names(df)[-1])
 tapply(unlist(df[-1]), grp, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You can also use `xtabs:

```
xtabs(vals~., na.omit(cbind(grp, vals = unlist(df[-1]))))
     Var2
Var1  111 112 113
  111 230 120  30
  112  50 130  40
  113 230  40  20
```

Comment: You beat me to the `tapply` answer - I think it can be simplified though: `tapply(unlist(df[-1]), expand.grid(df$Codes, names(df)[-1]), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @thelatemail well i included your solution. Though there was the `xtabs` option

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with actual matrices - especially with large ones -, expressing the operation as (sparse) linear algebra should be most efficient.

```r
library(Matrix) ## for sparse matrix operations

idx <- c("111","111","111","112","112","113")

mat <- matrix(c(100,10,20,NA,NA,10,
                10,20,40,NA,10,20,
                10,20,NA,NA,40,200,
                20,20,40,10,10,20,
                NA,NA,40,100,10,20,
                10,20,NA,30,10,20), 
              nrow=length(idx),
              byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(idx, idx))

## convert NA's to zero
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0

## examine matrix
mat

##     111 111 111 112 112 113
## 111 100  10  20   0   0  10
## 111  10  20  40   0  10  20
## 111  10  20   0   0  40 200
## 112  20  20  40  10  10  20
## 112   0   0  40 100  10  20
## 113  10  20   0  30  10  20

## indicator matrix
## converts between "code" and "idx" spaces
M_code_idx <- fac2sparse(idx)

## project to "code_code" space
M_code_idx %*% mat %*% t(M_code_idx)

## 3 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
##     111 112 113
## 111 230  50 230
## 112 120 130  40
## 113  30  40  20
```